# Not run the model with test_data - TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: is not an element of this graph

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, test-data

I build a Neural Network with two hidden layer.

```
from collections import namedtuple

def multilayer_perceptron():
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,train_x.shape[1]])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
    weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([train_x.shape[1], n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, 1]))
    }
    biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
    }
    # Hidden layer con funzione di attivazione ReLU
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(inputs, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    # Hidden layer with ReLU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    is_training=tf.Variable(True,dtype=tf.bool) 
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=out_layer )
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)  
    with tf.control_dependencies(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)):
         optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
    predicted = tf.nn.sigmoid(out_layer) 
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.round(predicted), y)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
    # Export the nodes 
    export_nodes = ['inputs', 'y', 'learning_rate','is_training', 'out_layer',
                    'cost', 'optimizer', 'predicted',  'accuracy'] 
    Graph = namedtuple('Graph', export_nodes)
    local_dict = locals()
    graph = Graph(*[local_dict[each] for each in export_nodes])
    return graph

pred1 = multilayer_perceptron()
```

Next I create a function for determinate the batch for input and output value:

```
def get_batch(data_x,data_y,batch_size=32):
    batch_n=len(data_x)//batch_size
    for i in range(batch_n):
        batch_x=data_x[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
        batch_y=data_y[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
        yield batch_x,batch_y

epochs = 25
train_collect = 20
train_print=train_collect*2

learning_rate_value = 0.001
batch_size=400

x_collect = []
train_loss_collect = []
train_acc_collect = []
valid_loss_collect = []
valid_acc_collect = []

saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

Finally I launch the session that print a Loss function and accuracy of train model. I save the result on file .ckpt

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    iteration=0
    for e in range(epochs):
        for batch_x,batch_y in get_batch(train_x,train_y,batch_size):
            iteration+=1
            feed = {pred1.inputs: train_x,
                    pred1.y: train_y,
                    pred1.learning_rate: learning_rate_value,
                    pred1.is_training:True
                   }
            train_loss, _, train_acc = sess.run([pred1.cost, pred1.optimizer, pred1.accuracy], feed_dict=feed)
            if iteration % train_collect == 0:
                x_collect.append(e)
                train_loss_collect.append(train_loss)
                train_acc_collect.append(train_acc)
                if iteration % train_print==0:
                     print("Epoch: {}/{}".format(e + 1, epochs),
                      "Train Loss: {:.4f}".format(train_loss),
                      "Train Acc: {:.4f}".format(train_acc))       
                feed = {pred1.inputs: valid_x,
                        pred1.y: valid_y,
                        pred1.is_training:False
                       }
                val_loss, val_acc = sess.run([pred1.cost, pred1.accuracy], feed_dict=feed)
                valid_loss_collect.append(val_loss)
                valid_acc_collect.append(val_acc) 
                if iteration % train_print==0:
                    print("Epoch: {}/{}".format(e + 1, epochs),
                      "Validation Loss: {:.4f}".format(val_loss),
                      "Validation Acc: {:.4f}".format(val_acc))
    saver.save(sess, "./insurance2.ckpt")
```

When I launch the session for data set the code give me an error:

```
model=multilayer_perceptron()
restorer=tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    restorer.restore(sess,"./insurance2.ckpt")
    feed={
        pred1.inputs:test_data,
        pred1.is_training:False
    }
    test_predict=sess.run(pred1.predicted,feed_dict=feed)
```

The two error are:

```
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 125), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 125), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

In my graph I export input.

Comment: What is pred1? You are instantiating the model in 'model' object

Comment: Model is an error, when I change pred1 with model the session go correctly. Stupid distraction error